# Activate a div hover with mouseover text link

Tags: javascript, css, hover, onmouseover

I'm trying to activate a div hover transition on mouse over so that my div will slide down with the text when I hover over "TEXT" but I can't seem to find the solution. I've seen numerous post about using containers for this, but those don't seem to work either.

```
        h1 {
           text-align: left;
           font-size:80px;
           font-family: Arial Black;
           color: red;
           }


        a {
          color: red;
          text-decoration: none;
          }

        a:hover{
        opacity: .6
          }


        div {
        float: right;
        font:12pt Arial;
        width:700px;
        height:0px;
        color:black;
        background: pink;
        transition: height .7s;
        -webkit-transition: height .7s; /* Safari */
            }
        div:hover{
        height:800px;
            }

         </head>
         </style>
         <body>

         <h1>
         <a onMouseOver = "document.getBlockElementById('div').style.display='';"
          onMouseOut="document.getBlockElementById('div').style.display='none';"
          href="" hover ="return false;"  style="color:#ff0000;text-decoration:none;">ART</a>
         <div class = "div">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ne consequat cotidieque. 
         Sit ut zril eirmod, accusam voluptatum interesset no sit. 
         Id per mollis sadipscing. Ut homero possim consequuntur ius, 
         id soluta meliore dissentiet nec.
         His errem corpora no, audire consulatu ea mea. Omnes petentium
         vel eu. Usu oblique voluptatibus ut, nullam consectetuer 
         voluptatibus ius an. Eu vero utroque cum, at case tractatos 
         prodesset eum. Ex animal equidem evertitur duo.
         Falli errem graece qui in, vim petentium efficiendi ad, usu 
         etiam ornatus iracundia id. In nec clita putant facilis, ne 
         mundi nonumy adipiscing est. Ad diam dolore verterem vel, eam 
         et malorum pericula scripserit. Eam cu euismod adipiscing 
         repudiandae, te mazim omnes eam, stet duis ea mel. Ne iusto 
         recteque pro, est te eleifend consequat voluptatibus. 
         Sit ea wisi eripuit. In summo facilis sadipscing vel, 
         vim consetetur scripserit ad. An sit eirmod euripidis. 
         Ad nam persecuti necessitatibus, eu choro sanctus vim, id 
         pri enim fierent euripidis. Illum utinam mei in, nec te 
         dolorem voluptatum efficiantur, duo eius necessitatibus an. 
         Persius veritus ei vim, vel eu alii dolor. Ei vix malorum 
         dolorem tractatos, vide adhuc probatus mea ex, nam omnis 
         ipsum splendide ut. At vim integre percipitur quaerendum, 
         qui dicant laoreet pertinacia ei. At erat minim copiosae ius, 
         te assum corrumpit ius, an has fabellas vituperata. Clita dictas 
         duo ut. Quot essent numquam ea per, nominati electram in pro.
         </span>
         </div>


         </h1> 

         </body>
         </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jYgAV/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it in pure CSS without any jQuery.

```
<a class="a-trigger">TEXT</a>
<div class="a-slide-down">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor text</div>
</div>
a.a-trigger{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:100px;
}
div.a-slide-down{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    position:relative;
display:block;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;    
}
a.a-trigger:hover ~ .a-slide-down{
    height:400px;
}
a.a-trigger:hover ~ .a-slide-down .text{
    margin-top:0px;
}
.a-slide-down .text{
    margin-top:-400px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pWQ2v/1/

Comment: Here was my CSS only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jYgAV/4/, but I like yours better.

Comment: Thank you, kind Sir. I did exactly as you but then it just wasn't giving the sliding effect for me.

Comment: That's interesting because I don't get the sliding effect with your code Lokesh Suthar, but I do get it with RustyToms' code.

Comment: Did you see the Fiddle link I provided at the bottom ?

Comment: Buddy the slide is working fine for me and even for @RustyToms but are you trying to say, this isn't the effect you want ?

Comment: it was the affect I wanted by for some reason Fiddle wasn't rendering it correctly on screen, but after implementing it in my own code the slide worked the way I wanted it to in the browser.

Comment: You're not using chrome are you ? Try this http://jsfiddle.net/pWQ2v/2/ I just defined transition for other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

HTML

```
<a id="sc" style="color:#ff0000;text-decoration:none;">TEXT</a>
    <div style="display:none">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ne consequat cotidieque. 
Sit ut zril eirmod, accusam voluptatum interesset no sit. 
Id per mollis sadipscing. Ut homero possim consequuntur ius, 
id soluta meliore dissentiet nec.
His errem corpora no, audire consulatu ea mea. Omnes petentium
vel eu. Usu oblique voluptatibus ut, nullam consectetuer 
voluptatibus ius an. Eu vero utroque cum, at case tractatos 
prodesset eum. Ex animal equidem evertitur duo.
Falli errem graece qui in, vim petentium efficiendi ad, usu 
etiam ornatus iracundia id. In nec clita putant facilis, ne 
mundi nonumy adipiscing est. Ad diam dolore verterem vel, eam 
et malorum pericula scripserit. Eam cu euismod adipiscing 
repudiandae, te mazim omnes eam, stet duis ea mel. Ne iusto 
recteque pro, est te eleifend consequat voluptatibus. 
Sit ea wisi eripuit. In summo facilis sadipscing vel, 
vim consetetur scripserit ad. An sit eirmod euripidis. 
Ad nam persecuti necessitatibus, eu choro sanctus vim, id 
pri enim fierent euripidis. Illum utinam mei in, nec te 
dolorem voluptatum efficiantur, duo eius necessitatibus an. 
Persius veritus ei vim, vel eu alii dolor. Ei vix malorum 
dolorem tractatos, vide adhuc probatus mea ex, nam omnis 
ipsum splendide ut. At vim integre percipitur quaerendum, 
qui dicant laoreet pertinacia ei. At erat minim copiosae ius, 
te assum corrumpit ius, an has fabellas vituperata. Clita dictas 
duo ut. Quot essent numquam ea per, nominati electram in pro.
</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('#sc').hover(function(){
      $('div').slideToggle('slow');
 });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jYgAV/3/)

Comment: Did you also use jquery on this?

Comment: yes i used.jquery makes this much easy you just include this on head `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: hmm for some reason this source code is registering in text wrangler.